# Правильно ли поставлено тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Скажите, правильно ли поставлено тире в данном предложении?

> В связи с трагическим событием – весь день траур.

Может, правильно будет:

> В связи с трагическим событием, весь день - траур.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Желательно записать так: *В связи с трагическим событием – **траур весь день**.*

**Пояснение**

1. Это предложение **эллиптического** вида (обстоятельство – подлежащее), тире обозначает паузу.
2. **Перестановка** вызвана тем, что грамматика выражения "весь день траур" неясная: можно прочитать "весь день является трауром" или "в течение всего дня траур".
3. *В связи с трагическим событием, весь день – траур.*

В этом предложении аналогичная ситуация, а обособление обстоятельства **нежелательно**, так как не требуется его актуализация (подчеркивание). Да и членение короткого предложения на три части не выглядит обоснованным.

4. В то же время выбранная структура предложения должна вписываться **в общий контекст**.